# Run matlab code through subprocess module in python

Tags: python, matlab, subprocess

I have a matlab code which I would like to call and execute via `subprocess` in my python
code. To run the matlab code via the terminal I have

`matlab2021a -nodesktop -r "addpath('path/to/dependencies'); matlab_file 1 1 0.5, exit"`

To replicate the same in my python script I do the following:

```
#myscript.py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(["matlab2021a",
                "-nodesktop", 
                "-r" , "addpath('/path/to/dependencies');", "/path/to/matlab_file", "1" , "1" ,"0.5", "exit"])
```

with the above code I end up within the matlab terminal `>>>` and I think my python script doesn't call the matlab file.

Can someone suggest the correct way to call and execute a matlab code while adding path for dependencies.

Comment: Everything after the `"-r"` needs to be one long string, not separate strings.  That's what the double quotes in your command-line do.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, but having a `;` before the matlab file path throws up `invalid use of operator` error

Comment: It shouldn't.  If it works in your terminal like that, it should work with `subprocess.run`.  After all, the shell is just creating an argv list, exactly like you are doing.

Comment: @TimRoberts so the error is due to providing the absolute file path with `/ ` in it. How to provide absolute path here?

Comment: You can use subprocess, but this will be easier: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: Presumably , you need to add the path in the `addpath` call.

Comment: Check out this video explaining how Call matlab function from python

https://www.mathworks.com/videos/how-to-call-matlab-from-python-1571136879916.html